# texstudio suddenly cannot show chinese bracket properly

Tags: texstudio

It happens yesterday, and is really annoying and drives me crazy.

When I type Chinese brackets in texstudio, it becomes like this

[image]

What is going on here? There is no such problem before. Even I reinstalled texstudio, the problems remains.

Comment: @Herbert It is indeed the font problem, change a chinese font solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll change it into an answer, then we can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the font of the editor, eg `Lucida Sans`:

```
  Options-> Configure Texstudio->Editor.
```

Comment: Hi, Herbert, there is a mistake. As I tested, `Lucida Sans Typewriter` is not OK. `Lucida Sans` is ok, or change to a chinese font will solve the problem.

Comment: it was only an idea. I'll correct it.